# Poner un enlace <a> dentro de una concatenacion en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Buen día
Estoy haciendo un buscador en tiempo real para un proyecto que tengo en PHP y MYSQL mediante AJAX, el buscador ya funciona al 100, me muestra los registros y todo. la manera en la que me muestra la tabla es por una concatenacion de una variable vacia; El codigo es el siguiente

```
<?php  while ($fila=$resultado-> fetch_assoc()){
            $salida.="<tr>
                    <td>".$fila['idcliente']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['nombre']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['telefono']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['direccion']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['diagnostico']."</td>
            </tr>";
        }
```

A este codigo quise agregarle un enlace para editar el registro mediante  de la siguiente manera

```
 <?php  while ($fila=$resultado-> fetch_assoc()){
            $salida.="<tr>
                    <td>".$fila['idcliente']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['nombre']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['telefono']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['direccion']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['diagnostico']."</td>
                    ///Este es el enlace
                    <td>".?><a class="link_edit"href="actualizar_cliente.php?id=<?php echo $data["idcliente"]; ?>">Editar</a> <?php."
                    </td>
            </tr>";
        }
```

El detalle está en que me da error y la verdad he intentado solucionarlo pero no lo he logrado
El error es el siguiente: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token ";" in C:\xampp\htdocs\PRUEBASAJAX\App\buscar.php on line 40
¿Alguna idea?
Gracias!

Comment: hola que tal, creo le el detalle en usar `""` despues del ultimo `<td>`, intenta así `<td>"."<a class='link_edit' href='actualizar_cliente.php?id='<?php echo $data['idcliente']; ?>' >Editar</a>'"."</td>`

Comment: @Artes Lo he intentado pero ahora me aparece este error: ´Parse error: syntax error, unexpected string content "", expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number´ Aun así muchisimas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: intenta asi: `<td> <a class='link_edit' href='actualizar_cliente.php?id="?><?php echo $data['idcliente'];">Editar</a></td></tr>"; 
}
?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando tengas que usar unas comillas dentro de una cadena entrecomillada debes escaparlas usando la barra invertida. Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
$cadena_entrecomillada = "Esta cadena tiene muchas \"comillas\"";
```

Si además tienes que usar variables de PHP, tienes dos opciones, que son ponerlas tal cual (si la cadena entrecomillada es con comillas dobles) o bien cerrar las comillas, concatenar la variable con la notación de punto (.) y volver a abrir las comillas. Ejemplos:

```
<?php
$nombre = "Alex";
$cadena_entrecomillada_con_variable_php_dentro = "$nombre, esta cadena tiene muchas \"comillas\"";
$cadena_entrecomillada_con_variable_php_concatenada = $nombre.", esta cadena tiene muchas \"comillas\"";
$cadena_entrecomillada_con_variable_php_concatenada_en_medio = "Esta cadena, ".$nombre.", tiene muchas \"comillas\"";
```

En caso de que las comillas fueran simples entonces **no** puedes poner la variable php dentro pues te dará un error. Deberás siempre usar la concatenación. Ejemplo:

```
<?php
$cadena_entrecomillada_con_variable_php = $nombre.', esta cadena tiene muchas "comillas"';
```

Como ves, en este último caso, no estoy escapando las comillas dobles porque estan encerradas entre comillas simples y no hace falta.

Explicado todo esto, ahora ponlo así y nos comentas si te funciona (por cierto, he cambiado `$data["idcliente"]` por `$fila["idcliente"]` porque diria que tenias un error allí:

```
 <?php
while ($fila=$resultado-> fetch_assoc()){
    $salida.="
        <tr>
            <td>".$fila['idcliente']."</td>
            <td>".$fila['nombre']."</td>
            <td>".$fila['telefono']."</td>
            <td>".$fila['direccion']."</td>
            <td>".$fila['diagnostico']."</td>
            <td><a class=\"link_edit\" href=\"actualizar_cliente.php?id=".$fila["idcliente"]."\">Editar</a></td>
        </tr>";
}
```

Comment: Wow! Funciono a la perfección, muchisimas gracias, no había caido en cuenta con ese detalle, me salvaste la vida

Comment: Creo que mis ejemplos de la respuesta pueden ser un poco confusos, pero es algo que si usas PHP debes aprender a utilizar muy bien para que el código no sea un lio de narices, je.  También te recomiendo que uses un editor de código con sintaxis highlight para que te pinte el código pues te ayudará mucho a arreglar esas cosas. Me alegro que te haya funcionado!  Saludos